# WordPress - Duplicate entry for Primary Key when updating post meta via concurrent AJAX calls

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, asynchronous

I'm using [Async Request](https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing) to update WordPress post meta in a loop.

Some people using my code are telling me that it errors, and in their logs, they're finding things like:

> [Fri Sep 30 15:12:28.782842 2016] [:error] [pid 19006] [client
>   127.0.0.1:57559] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '296520' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`,
>   `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (7637, 'my_titles',
>   'a:1:{i:0;O:19:\"My_Title_Item\":8:{s:25:\"\0My_Title_Item\0text\";s:90:\"User
>   text\";s:35:\"\0My_Title_Item\0start_datetime\";O:8:\"DateTime\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:19:\"2016-09-29
>   11:28:58\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:3:\"UTC\";}s:33:\"\0My_Title_Item\0end_datetime\";b:0;s:27:\"\0My_Title_Item\0pre_my\";b:1;s:24:\"\0My_Title_Item\0uid\";s:10:\"6971607559\";s:35:\"\0My_Title_Item\0visits_per_day\";N;s:27:\"\0My_Title_Item\0errors\";b:0;s:7:\"updated\";O:8:\"DateTime\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:19:\"2016-09-30
>   15:12:15\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:3:\"UTC\";}}}')
>   made by do_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_my_patch_my_async'),
>   call_user_func_array, WP_Async_Request->maybe_handle,
>   My_Patch_YR->handle, My_Title_History->__construct,
>   My_Title_History->maybe_initialise_titles,
>   My_Title_History->get_titles, My_Title_History->maybe_reset_errors,
>   My_Title_History->reset_errors_on_latest_title,
>   My_Title_History->save_titles_db, update_post_meta, update_metadata,
>   add_metadata, referer:
>   https://samplesite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_my_patch_my_async&nonce=068b8bd7f8

The important part being `WordPress database error Duplicate entry '296520' for key 'PRIMARY' for query....`.

I believe this is happening because the asynchronous code execution is achieved via `wp_ajax`, and I wonder if it's running multiple requests concurrently?

Is there a way, therefore, to make sure that the key is incremented when running this (if I replace `update_post_meta` with a direct `$wpdb` `INSERT` command) ?

Thanks!

Comment: once I had stumbled upon similar problem when I accidentally removed auto increment from primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REPAIR TABLE wp_postmeta
```

It worked for me.

Php memory was okay, Apache memory was okay, htaccess was okay, etc etc.

The table was corrupted somehow (probably an interruption when someone was uploading an image on the backend and say, navigating from the web page, breaking the complete "INSERT" command WP does. So, just repair the table and voila!  Works.